# Angular-cli and npm can't install node modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I want to make a new angular 7 project. When I run the command "ng new portfolio" I can set everything to what I want (routing and stylesheet). This works, but when it comes to installing the node modules, I get an error:

```
813 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden: @angular/animations@~7.0.0
813 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
813 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
813 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
813 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
813 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
813 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
813 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
813 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
813 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
813 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
813 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
813 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
814 verbose cwd D:\Development\Webdevelopment\portfolio
815 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
816 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
817 verbose node v10.15.0
818 verbose npm  v6.4.1
819 error code E403
820 error 403 Forbidden: @angular/animations@~7.0.0
821 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The problem is I can't install the node modules. Next, I searched through the web and found some answers that can eventually help.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10692) they say I should run my command prompt in administrator mode or reset the proxy configuration. I made the changes and deleted the project. Then I tried ng new again. That didn't work either. Then I got an idea. I could install the node modules by myself with npm install. I tried that and got an error:

```
810 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden: @angular/animations@~7.0.0
810 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
810 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
810 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
810 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
810 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
810 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
810 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
810 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
810 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
810 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
810 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
810 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
811 verbose cwd D:\Development\Webdevelopment\portfolio
812 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
813 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
814 verbose node v10.15.0
815 verbose npm  v6.4.1
816 error code E403
817 error 403 Forbidden: @angular/animations@~7.0.0
818 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: did you tried clearing npm cache

Comment: yep, helped exactly nothing

Comment: try cloning this https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit.git and use `npm install` there

Comment: When I ge the error again I try this. Thanks :)